# "Back to original position" button in the PGN viewer

Tags: feature-request, pgn-viewer

Probably most of you had experienced this: you play through a game that was started from some middlegame position, then at the end you would like to go back to the position **from which the game was posted**. Here is an example (note that it starts at black's 34<sup>th</sup> move):

```
[Site "https://lichess.org/kuvnBssO"]
[Date "2018.07.20"]
[Round "-"]
[White "Kulkid"]
[Black "WaisKamal"]
[Result "0-1"]
[WhiteElo "2016"]
[BlackElo "2107"]
[Variant "Standard"]
[TimeControl "30+0"]
[ECO "D44"]
[Termination "Normal"]
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]
[SeUp "1"]
[StartPly "67"]

1. d4 d5 2. c4 Nf6 3. Nc3 e6 4. Nf3 dxc4 5. e3 { D44 Queen's Gambit Declined: Vienna Variation, Quiet Variation } Be7 6. Bxc4 O-O 7. Bd3 Nbd7 8. O-O b6 9. Re1 Bb7 10. a3 Bxf3 11. b4 Bxd1 12. Rxd1 c5 13. Bb2 cxd4 14. exd4 Qc7 15. Ne2 Rac8 16. Rac1 Qb7 17. Rb1 Rc7 18. f3 Rfc8 19. Ng3 h6 20. Ne4 Nxe4 21. Bxe4 Qb8 22. Bd3 Bf6 23. Ba6 Rd8 24. Be2 b5 25. Kf2 a6 26. Bc1 Nf8 27. Be3 Rdd7 28. Rdc1 Rxc1 29. Rxc1 Qd8 30. Rd1 Bxd4 31. Bxd4 Rxd4 32. Rc1 Rd2 33. Re1 Ng6 34. Ke3 f5 35. Kf2 Nf4 36. Kg3 Nxe2+ 37. Kf2 Qd4+ 38. Kf1 Qg1# { Black wins by checkmate. }
```

Now after playing through the game, you would like to go back to the starting point from which the diagram started (which is often the point where the action starts, especially if there are analysis lines). Instead of reloading the page to have the diagram start at that point, can we have a button that goes to that position?